# How to prefix every command in shell with "sg - grp -c"?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, shell

I am using bash shell. I want to run all commands of a specific user to be run as a specific group command in the shell. How can I do it? Can anything be can be done in ~/.bashrc ?

Comment: Please clarify: if you want him to run "_all_ commands" under "a specific group", is there a reason why you don't change `/etc/passwd` to make that group his default?  Alternatively, what about putting a `newgrp command` in his ~/.bashrc?  Or, is there a specific feature of `sg` that you need?

Comment: what should i change in `/etc/passwd` ?? i dont think `newgrp` doesnt do anything rather than creating a group :)

Comment: You are thinking of `groupadd`.  I wrote up more on how to safely change group identity in `/etc/passwd` below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a user wants to spend the rest of his session in somegroup, he can run `newgrp`, as in:

```
newgrp somegroup
```

He may or may not be prompted for a password depending on permissions.  See `man newgrp` for details.

The group that the user is in when he starts his session is determined by the fourth field of his line of the `/etc/passwd` file.  If you don't want to futz with that file directly, there are system utilities to modify it safely.  One is `usermod`:

```
usermod -g somegroup someuser
```

(`somegroup` should exist before you run this.)  After running the above, the next time that `someuser` logs in, he will, by default, be in `somegroup`.

For information on how to interpret the fields in the `/etc/passwd` file, see `man 5 passwd`  (the "5" is important).  Groups and their corresponding group numbers are defined in the `/etc/group` file.  See `man 5 group` for more info on it.